# Adding docblocks to unit tests

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I normally don't ever see docblocks with unit tests, I wonder what the convention is here. I can't seem to be able to find much information about this.

My reasoning is that the unit tests should speak for themselves about what they do, with descriptive names. It is also not part of the regular codebase that's why typehinting and setting up proper docblocks for IDE's is of less value.

Also mixing docblocks with the comment style `@dataProvider` syntax gets pretty ugly real fast.

What is the convention here and what do people use?